# MappedSuperclass - SequenceGenerator in Subclass (hibernate 5.2.13.Final)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We tried upgrading hibernate version in out project form 5.2.X to 5.2.13.Final ,
but new hibernate correctly forces

> The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).

Our clas structure consists of one BaseEntity and subclasses with defined @GenericGenerator, all generators use the same name.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="idGenerator")
  private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_TABLE")
@GenericGenerator(strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", name = "idGenerator", parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM, value = "SAMPLE_SEQ") })
public class SampleEntity extends BaseEntity
```

Is there an option to correct this generators definitions without placing **id** field in every class?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for us on Hibernate 5.2.1 & postgres:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = [
                Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY, value = "true"),
                Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.OPT_PARAM, value = "pooled"),
                Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INITIAL_PARAM, value = "1"),
                Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50")
            ]
    )
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

Code is in kotlin but you could easily transform it into java.

If you need more info on SequenceStyleGenerator, see [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html)

Comment: thanks for this. You ended some hours of Googling